# operation on a variable inside a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

I'm new with oop and python. I've been trying to do a simple thing:
there is class called Foo(),it contains a variable called x which is initially set to zero.

```
>>>a = Foo()
>>>a.x
>>>0
```

now I want to give a new value to x so:

```
>>>p.x = 1983
```

now a math operation should happen to x, for instance 1 is add to x.now x is 1984,so now when I call x:

```
>>> p.x
>>> 1984
```

also the program should check that whether or not the value given to x is negative or not.If it is negative it should return -1.
I did this but it didn't work:(as I said it should do some mathematical operation on x,the operation itself is not really important)

```
class Foo():
    x = 0
    if x > 0:
        x %= 100
    elif x < 0:
        x = -1
```

I really don't now how should I update a class variable in they I mentioned.
Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Do you know how to increment a regular variable? Have you tried doing the same thing, just with the instance variable?

Comment: Please share the class definition for Foo.

Comment: Are you expected to change the class `Foo` to get this behavior, or write something that receives a `Foo` object and updates it in the expected manner? What code have you written so far?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I edited my post and added my attempt

Comment: `p.x` is more or less similar to any python variable in terms of operations. p is the instance of class `Foo` so if you do `p.x=p.x+1` you should be able to increment the value of THAT instance only.

Comment: Looks like a task for a `property` but according to the code sample the OP still has some basic problems understanding classes.

Comment: @Matthias: `property`s don't work on class attributes though (they *are* class attributes that implement the descriptor protocol, which intercept *instance* attribute lookup). Making this work for a class attribute would require you to define a metaclass with the `property` and make `Foo` use that metaclass, which is getting *way* into the weeds. I want to know whether this should be a class attribute at all (seems like it's used on instances, and should perhaps be an instance attribute) and if so, why it needs this sort of complexity.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  I want that class to understands that when I changed the value of x ,it should do the operation on the new x by the class itself so I don't need to call that function by my self.It would look something like this: p.x = 1983 now the operation has taken place so the next time I say: print(p.x) it gives back 83. of course the greater question for me is that is it even possible to run a method in class within the class itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't need actual class attributes (you're always constructing an instance of `Foo` to use the attribute anyway, and it's not common for class attributes to be both public and logically mutable), the correct solution is to make `x` [a `property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) that wraps an *instance* attribute, which has independent values per instance, established in the `__init__` initializer for the class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0  # _x is a protected instance attr that the property uses behind the scenes

    @property
    def x(self):  # getter for x is normal
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, newx):  # setter for x massages the value before setting it
        if newx >= 0:  # Cheaper to handle 0 on same code path as > 0 so you needn't test < 0
            newx %= 100
        else:
            newx = -1
        self._x = newx
```

Usage is pretty simple:

```
>>> myfoo = Foo()
>>> myfoo.x = 1983
>>> myfoo.x
83
>>> myfoo.x = -3748972983
>>> myfoo.x
-1
```

In case it really needs to be a class attribute *and* it must be accessible on instances, the solution gets ugly, as you need [a metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) to provide `property`s on classes, and additional properties on the class itself to delegate access on instances to the class itself.

Note: **I *strongly* discourage actually doing this as anything other than an exercise**:

```
class FooMeta(type):  # Inheriting from type makes metaclass
    @property
    def x(cls):
        return cls._x
    @x.setter
    def x(cls, newx):
        if newx >= 0:
            newx %= 100
        else:
            newx = -1
        cls._x = newx

class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):
    _x = 0
    # Must make properties on class if instances are to "benefit" from class property
    @property
    def x(self):
        return type(self).x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, newx):
        type(self).x = newx
```

That allows the following to work:

```
>>> Foo.x  # x exists on Foo itself, not just instances
>>> Foo.x = 1983
>>> Foo.x
83
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.x  # Accessible on instances too
83
>>> f.x = -234789
>>> f.x  # Same behavior on instance
-1
>>> Foo.x  # Changing instance changed class
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help. You should refactor your class definition as below

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=0
    def check_x(self):
        if self.x > 0:
            return (self.x % 100)
        elif self.x < 0:
            return -1
p=Foo()
print(p.x) # 0
p.x=1983
p.check_x() # 83
```

Check for negative values

```
p.x=-100
p.check_x() # -1
```

Comment: This still contains a mix of the usage of class attributes and instance attributes.

Comment: @mad_ thank you for you answer but I didn't want to do something like p.check_c(), what I wanted to do is to set p.x and then automatically the operation happens to it, so the next time I call p.x it returns a changed value.

Comment: @mad_ actually I won't: at first p.x = 0; then I will assign it to: p.x = 1983.Now If I call p.x in idle it still is 1983 and not 83.In order for then operation to take place I have to call p.check_x. What I want is that the check_x function runs in the class itself or something like that so I don't need to call the method from outside.

Comment: @mad_ I want that class to understands that when I changed the value of x ,it should do the operation on the new x by the class itself so I don't need to call that function by my self.It would look something like this: `p.x = 1983` now the operation has taken place so the next time I say: `print(p.x)` it gives back 83

Comment: @mad_ I believe you should look at ShadowRangers' answer.