# How can I clobber a property within a subcass?

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to create a `Config` Python 3 class where users set configuration params as either plain class attributes on a super class or as properties on a super class that users can set override/shadow on instances of the (sub)class. I'd rather not have require users to define setter methods for attributes that were created using property methods. Is there a way I can clobber an attribute set in a parent class even when it was created using a property decorator?

```
class Configuration:
    param1 = 'a'

    @property
    def param2(self):
        return self.param1 + 'x'

class Proj1(Configuration):
    param3 = 'blah'

config = Proj1()
config.param2 = 'new_val'
```

This code snippet would throw an `AttributeError` with the attempted assignment to the `pram2` attrbute because of the property decorate in the superclass. Is there a way I can easily clobber this existing property and shadow it with an arbitrary attribute value?

Comment: *"I'd rather not have require users to define setter methods"* – Then define your own default setter in the parent class…?

Comment: Do you want the clobbering value to be an instance attribute or a class attribute of `Proj1`? Do you want it to use the default value from the parent when not clobbered? Is using class attributes what you actually want here? Usually the correct design is to use instance attributes.

Comment: As [`deceze`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) said, what's wrong with defining a setter for the property? By the way, this would totally work on Python 2.x even without a setter (which is not a good thing, but still...)

Comment: I'm trying to keep the API as minimal as possible. I want users to just be able to define simple parameters (ie class attributes) and derived attributes (which I'm using property decorators for). So asking users to also define accompanying setters is not the best outcome. Maybe properties just isn't the best approach for these "derived" parameters.

Comment: @zwer: Note: It only works on Python 2 if you use old-style classes; new-style classes will behave just as in Python 3. Frankly, I'm surprised the `@property` works at all on Python 2 with old-style classes; old-style classes [aren't supposed to provide support for descriptors or properties](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class) ("Only new-style classes can use Python’s newer, versatile features like `__slots__`, descriptors, properties, and `__getattribute__()`."), but I guess it's that they don't support them *correctly*, they do have some stumbling support for them.

Comment: @nedned: Why not define the setter in the parent then? You can still make it operate on the subclass or instance (and even type check if you want to make sure it's never invoked on the parent class itself).

Comment: @nedned - But if your users are not defining setters then their (custom) properties will act just as they define them (i.e. simple class attributes), and you can define your getters/setters for the properties they'll inherit in the base class. I'm struggling to see what's your issue here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, from the perspective of the user, I just want `config.param2` to result in the newly assigned value (`new_val` in this case). When not clobbered, the property method on the parent should be evaluated. I'm only using class attributes because it results in a simple API. How would you use instance attributes here?

Comment: @zwer, I probably haven't been as clear as I could be. Users are working with both the parent and child config classes. The motivating use case is having shared parameters across multiple projects (that I'm setting on the `Configuration` class) and then which can be overridden within subclasses which represent distinct projects.

Comment: @nedned: I'm mostly concerned you're overengineering, using class hierarchies where instances of a class would be more appropriate. Typically, class attributes are either logical constants, or used for implementation details (e.g. counting the number of objects created, providing some interning facility to avoid creation of objects with duplicate values, etc.) where outside mutation doesn't occur. And if you're using them for nothing but class attributes, it makes little sense to create instances of them. I'm worried you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, you may well be right. I have a bit of a penchant for over engineering things. I will ponder some more what I'm actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your goal is to make the derived attribute immutable on the parent, but let child classes mutate it without requiring child classes to define an `@setter` to do so. So just make the parent define subclass friendly property getters and setters that explicitly forbid operating on the parent class itself:

```
class Configuration:
    param1 = 'a'

    @property
    def param2(self):
        try:
            return self._param2  # If child has an override, use that value
        except AttributeError:
            return self.param1 + 'x'  # Otherwise use parent default

    @param2.setter
    def param2(self, new_val):
        # Treat as immutable on parent
        if type(self) is Configuration:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        # But allow it to be set on child
        self._param2 = new_val  # Or type(self)._param2 = new_val if it should be set on class

    @param2.deleter
    def param2(self):
        # Treat as immutable on parent
        if type(self) is Configuration:
            raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
        del self._param2  # Or del type(self)._param2 if it's a class attribute, not instance
```

Now instances of your child can clobber, unclobber, etc., but the original parent class can't be changed (you could manually do `Configuration._param2 = 'new value'`, but that's violating the implementation detail convention for underscore prefixed names).

Note that if you *need* these properties to wrap class attributes, not instance attributes (so changing `config.param2` should change `param2` for all other instances of `Proj1`), for consistency, you'd want the behavior to work when directly assigning `Proj1.param2` as well. This gets ugly, as defining a `property` that works on direct access to the class attribute via the class, not the instance, requires a metaclass. I won't get into the details here, but you can read more at the bottom of [my answer to a question that demanded a similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52560670/364696).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what I mean under defining a setter in the base class, consider this:

```
class Configuration:

    param1 = "a"

    @property
    def param2(self):
        return getattr(self, "_param2", self.param1 + "x")

    @param2.setter
    def param2(self, value):
        self._param2 = value


class Proj1(Configuration):

    param3 = "blah"

config = Proj1()
print(config.param2)  # ax
config.param2 = "new_val"
print(config.param2)  # new_val
```

And you can do the same for any class attribute you expect to be overriden at will of the user.

Comment: Why `setattr(self, "_param2", value)`? `self._param2 = value` is going to be faster and clearer; the only reason to use `setattr` is if the name to set is dynamic (unlike `getattr`, which also serves a purpose for providing default values when the attribute is missing, though `try` direct access/`except AttributeError` compute default is often faster, as it avoids computing the default when it can avoid doing so).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Fair point. It just looks nicer to have it as a counterpart to `getattr()`. Either way, I was trying to show my point, not necessarily define the API.

Comment: I can forgive a compulsive need for symmetry. I'd be a major hypocrite if I couldn't. :-)